# count contiguous NaN values by unique values

Tags: python, pandas

I have contiguous periods of NaN values by code. I want to count NaN values from periods of contiguous NaN values by code, and also i want the start and end date of the contiguos period of NaN values.

```
df :
                         CODE        TMIN
1998-01-01 00:00:00        12         2.5
1999-01-01 00:00:00        12         NaN
2000-01-01 00:00:00        12         NaN
2001-01-01 00:00:00        12         2.2
2002-01-01 00:00:00        12         NaN
1998-01-01 00:00:00        41         NaN
1999-01-01 00:00:00        41         NaN
2000-01-01 00:00:00        41         5.0
2001-01-01 00:00:00        41         9.0
2002-01-01 00:00:00        41         8.0
1998-01-01 00:00:00        52         2.0
1999-01-01 00:00:00        52         NaN
2000-01-01 00:00:00        52         NaN
2001-01-01 00:00:00        52         NaN
2002-01-01 00:00:00        52         1.0
1998-01-01 00:00:00        91         NaN


Expected results :
       Start_Date      End date                CODE        number of contiguous missing values 
1999-01-01 00:00:00    2000-01-01 00:00:00      12                            2
2002-01-01 00:00:00    2002-01-01 00:00:00      12                            1
1998-01-01 00:00:00    1999-01-01 00:00:00      41                            2
1999-01-01 00:00:00    2001-01-01 00:00:00      52                            3
1998-01-01 00:00:00    1998-01-01 00:00:00      91                            1
```

How can i solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try groupby the cumsum of non-null:

```
df['group'] = df.TMIN.notna().cumsum()

(df[df.TMIN.isna()]
   .groupby(['group','CODE'])
   .agg(Start_Date=('group', lambda x: x.index.min()),
        End_Date=('group', lambda x: x.index.max()),
        cont_missing=('TMIN', 'size')
       )
)
```

Output:

```
                     Start_Date             End_Date  cont_missing
group CODE                                                        
1     12    1999-01-01 00:00:00  2000-01-01 00:00:00             2
2     12    2002-01-01 00:00:00  2002-01-01 00:00:00             1
      41    1998-01-01 00:00:00  1999-01-01 00:00:00             2
6     52    1999-01-01 00:00:00  2001-01-01 00:00:00             3
7     91    1998-01-01 00:00:00  1998-01-01 00:00:00             1
```